# How to Reel parts from Cut-Tape?

Tags: manufacturing

How does Digi-Key make Digi-Reels (or Mouser make Mouser-Reels, or whatever)? That is to say, given parts in Cut-Tape form, what tools and additional materials are needed to add a leader to support spooling onto a tape feeder? The picture below shows some kind of foil that bonds the leader to the cut tape in such a way as to keep the pitch consistent through the join. Is it plausible / cost-effective to do this on my own instead of paying a reeling fee to distributors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a cut tape splicer - this company seems to sell a few, along with the necessary supplies: http://www.tapesplice.com

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Seems a lot like splicing motion-picture film.  Some reels have holes that look a lot like Super 8 motion picture film, but the perforations shown above don't match either Super 8 nor "regular" 8mm film.

Answer (score 8):

If the junction is not clean, the edge will jam the feeder. Also, the brass will often stick on the sprocket. It does work occasionally but you can also be in for some fun clearing the feeder. Hopefully it isn't on customer tour day because it isn't pretty.

Comment: I would have upvoted this if it weren't for the sloppy lack of capitalization of the first letter of each sentence.  We do engineering here, where neatness and attention to detail matter.  A lot.

Comment: I upvoted just because someone else is whining.